# EWOULDBLOCK equivalent errno under Windows Perl

Tags: windows, perl, magic-numbers, errno

G'day Stackoverflowers,

I'm the author of Perl's [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie) pragma, which changes Perl's built-ins to throw exceptions on failure.  It's similar to [Fatal](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Fatal), but with lexical scope, an extensible exception model, more intelligent return checking, and much, much nicer error messages.  It will be replacing the `Fatal` module in future releases of Perl (provisionally 5.10.1+), but can currently be downloaded from the CPAN for Perl 5.8.0 and above.

The next release of `autodie` will add special handling for calls to `flock` with the `LOCK_NB` (non-blocking) option.  While a failed `flock` call would normally result in an exception under `autodie`, a failed call to `flock` using `LOCK_NB` will merely return false if the returned errno (`$!`) is `EWOULDBLOCK`.

The reason for this is so people can continue to write code like:

```
use Fcntl qw(:flock);

use autodie;   # All perl built-ins now succeed or die.

open(my $fh, '<', 'some_file.txt');

my $lock = flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);  # Lock the file if we can.

if ($lock) {
    # Opportuntistically do something with the locked file.
}
```

In the above code, a lock that fails because someone else has the file locked already (`EWOULDBLOCK`) is not considered to be a hard error, so autodying `flock` merely returns a false value.  In the situation that we're working with a filesystem that doesn't support file-locks, or a network filesystem and the network just died, then autodying `flock` generates an appropriate exception when it sees that our errno is not `EWOULDBLOCK`.

This works just fine in my dev version on Unix-flavoured systems, but it fails horribly under Windows.  It appears that while Perl under Windows supports the `LOCK_NB` option, it doesn't define `EWOULDBLOCK`.  Instead, the errno returned is 33 ("Domain error") when blocking would occur.

Obviously I can hard-code this as a constant into `autodie`, but that's not what I want to do here, because it means that I'm screwed if the errno ever changes (or has changed).  I would love to compare it to the Windows equivalent of `POSIX::EWOULDBLOCK`, but I can't for the life of me find where such a thing would be defined.  If you can help, let me know.

Answers I specifically don't want:

- Suggestions to hard-code it as a constant (or worse still, leave a magic number floating about).
- Not supporting `LOCK_NB` functionality at all under Windows.
- Assuming that any failure from a `LOCK_NB` call to `flock` should return merely false.
- Suggestions that I ask on p5p or [perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/).  I already know about them.
- An explanation of how `flock`, or exceptions, or `Fatal` work.  I already know.  Intimately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under Win32 "native" Perl, note that $^E is more descriptive at 33, "The process cannot access the file because another process locked a portion of the file" which is `ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION` (available from [Win32::WinError](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-WinError/)).

Answer (score 5):

For the Windows-specific error code, you want to use `$^E`.  In this case, it's 33: "The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file" (`ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION` in `winerror.h`).

Unfortunately, I don't think [Win32::WinError](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-WinError/) is in core.  On the other hand, if Microsoft ever renumbered the Windows error codes, pretty much every Windows program ever written would stop working, so I don't think there'll be a problem with hardcoding it.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!  I'm not too flustered with Win32::WinError not being core.  If it exists, I can pull the constant from it.  If it doesn't I can always fall back on the hard-coded (but unsightly) value of 33.

Thanks again!

  Paul

Comment: Win32::WinError is likely in the "Windows Core", that is, one of the modules that is included in every Win32 distribution of Perl (like everything in the "libwin32" bundle).